Middleware is enough to protect the api route and app?
Hello I just wanted to know if the middleware was enough to protect the application. For example if I have api routes and server actions to get/add data in my database and only the /dashbord route calls these elements. I need to add a session check before getting the data or creating it. I specify that the route/dashbord is protected by middleware
To explain better for example I have 3 roads. One to connect, then one for home and one for dashbord.
/dashbord is protected by middleware (only logged-in users can access it). In my dashbord route I make calls to my route api and I can for example create something with a form (server action). Do I need to double check if the session exists before calling api or does middleware protect that?
next 14
next-auth 5

Thank you
